# Azure webapp deployment

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I am studying to do my AZ-204 exam and have come across a bank of questions. There is a question I am trying to get my head around and it is todo with deploying a webapp via the cli. The answer I would give is different in one place and that is the binding of a hostname via `az webapp config hostname`

Here is the question that is being asked

```
Fourth Coffee has an ASP.NET Core web app that runs in Docker. The app is mapped to the www.fourthcoffee.com domain.
Fourth Coffee is migrating this application to Azure.
You need to provision an App Service Web App to host this docker image and map the custom domain to the App Service web app.
A resource group named FourthCoffeePublicWebResourceGroup has been created in the WestUS region that contains an App Service Plan named
AppServiceLinuxDockerPlan.
Which order should the CLI commands be used to develop the solution? To answer, move all of the Azure CLI commands from the list of commands to the answer area and arrange them in the correct order.
Select and Place:
```

[image]

the order I put would be id the ansers are numbers 1 - 4 from top to bottom

4, 3, 2, 1

but the answer is
[image]

My qyestion really is, how can you set a hostname of a webapp that has not been created or is this a dodgy website that has not properly copied the answers. The microsoft documentation does not provide any answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer should be 4 3 1 2 or 4 3 2 1 (it doesn't matter)

4 - Set any required variables

3 - Create the webapp

1 - Configure the container

2 - Set the fully qualified domain name

or you could go with 4 3 2 1

The answer provided in the screenshot shot is wrong, you cannot add the hostname before you create the web app.

This is probably a dodgy website that has no idea how containers and webapps work